# Can the culture of 500 people last after 1000 years?

Tags: population

A cabal of necromantic nobles and their (human) servants and retinues fled west after their expulsion from the old empire.

They landed in a new, mostly wild realm. Probably a fifth of the colonists died during their initial adjustment - the land would be heavily forested and not particularly fertile, as well as prone to raids.

Slowly, many would eventually fuse into the surrounding clans - dark knights marrying into the chiefs' families if they abide by tithes of blood sacrifice.

After 1000 years of this, assuming the clans greatly outnumber the colonists (though only a few being actually friendly/willing to breed), is it safe to say there would be little to no "imperial" culture left after a millenia, aside from their ancient undead masters? Or could there still be "civilized" colonists that trace their descent (mostly) back to the original colonists rather than the clans?

Comment: Well, Christianity supposedly began from one man, his twelve close followers and his mother. Two millenia later it's the main cultural background of the western civilization.

Comment: This is something that's entirely up to you as a worldbuilder. Perhaps rocks fall and everyone dies instantly, perhaps a thousand years later the culture survives. There are far too many variables for us to be able to definitively provide an answer one way or another. But you as worldbuilder can chose whatever outcome you would like to see and construct your world so that is what happens.

Comment: Welcome Lorsh. I see no reason whatever that you couldn't write it that way quite credibly. Could you tell us what problem it is you'd like solving here? Please take our [tour] and refer to the [help] for guidance, then you can [edit] to ask your question. Perhaps the key is in whether the necromantic capability is inherited or just learned and how much pride/shame in family-heritage plays a part.

Comment: Er, clans?  Chiefs?  Dark knights?  Who are all these people?  Definitions, please?

Comment: Culture is always a reaction to the environment. When the environment changes, so does the culture. That is why groups that want to preserve a culture attempt to recreate the environment - see Chinatown, "little Italy", etc. But when the environment is radically different, it eats away at the resources needed to recreate and thus, the culture slowly changes.

Answer (score 1):

**Ancient undead masters will keep the culture going.**

You need to be able to speak the language of your ancient undead master!  Also the ancient undead master will be alarmed if you show up with a bunch of weird piercings and funky clan clothes.  "What the heck?" your master will groan.  "Go back upstairs and change!".  The ancient undead masters are not up for learning new dances because the ones they know are perfectly good and you had better be able to play the songs that go with them.  Those good songs from the old country, now.  Not some clan song with funky rhythms.

The ancient undead masters do not eat too much and have a minimal sense of smell, so culinary styles could borrow from the clan locals without the masters taking too much notice.

The ancient undead masters are not too flexible.  These folks were also like that before they went undead and the undeadening did not help at all.